# Why does lag() in this data frame repeat and reverse calculations?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, calculated-columns

This is a data frame I've called CA_less, which I want to use to calculate GDP change over five decades:

| CountryName | Year | GDP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Costa Rica | 1960 | 507513829.9949 |
| Costa Rica | 2010 | 37268635287.0856 |
| Guatemala | 1960 | 1043599900 |
| Guatemala | 2010 | 41338595380.8159 |
| Honduras | 1960 | 335650000 |
| Honduras | 2010 | 15839344591.9842 |
| Panama | 1960 | 537147100 |
| Panama | 2010 | 28917200000 |

I used this code:

```
CA_GDP_decade <- mutate(CA_less, Year2 = lag(Year, 1),GDP2 = lag(GDP, 1), CHANGE_PERC = ((GDP - GDP2) / GDP2 ) * 100 %>% 
mutate_if(is.numeric,
            round,
            digits = 0)
CA_GDP_decade
```

I was expecting this:

| CountryName | Year | GDP | Year2 | GDP2 | Change_perc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Costa Rica | 1960 | 507513830 | NA | NA | NA |
| Costa Rica | 2010 | 37268635287 | 1960 | 507513830 | 7243 |
| Guatemala | 2010 | 41338595381 | 1960 | 1043599900 | 3861 |
| Honduras | 2010 | 15839344592 | 1960 | 335650000 | 4619 |
| Panama | 2010 | 28917200000 | 1960 | 537147100 | 5283 |

However, I got this instead:

| CountryName | Year | GDP | Year2 | GDP2 | Change_perc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Costa Rica | 1960 | 507513830 | NA | NA | NA |
| Costa Rica | 2010 | 37268635287 | 1960 | 507513830 | 7243 |
| Guatemala | 1960 | 1043599900 | 2010 | 37268635287 | -97 |
| Guatemala | 2010 | 41338595381 | 1960 | 1043599900 | 3861 |
| Honduras | 1960 | 335650000 | 2010 | 41338595381 | -99 |
| Honduras | 2010 | 15839344592 | 1960 | 335650000 | 4619 |
| Panama | 1960 | 537147100 | 2010 | 15839344592 | -97 |
| Panama | 2010 | 28917200000 | 1960 | 537147100 | 5283 |

How could I use lag() in such a way that I avoid the duplication and reversal of the operations?

Comment: You probably want to `group_by(CountryName)`. I don't know what you mean by "reversal". My guess is by "duplication" you mean that you have the same number of rows. If you want 1 row per group in the result, use `summarize` not `mutate`.

Comment: Thank you. Apologies for the scrambled table. I can't sort out its format.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your original code you could so something like this.

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(
  CountryName = c("Costa Rica","Costa Rica","Guatemala","Guatemala","Honduras","Honduras","Panama","Panama"),
  Year = c(1960,2010,1960,2010,1960,2010,1960,2010),
  GDP = c(507513829.9949,37268635287.0856, 1043599900, 41338595380.8159, 335650000, 15839344591.9842, 537147100, 28917200000.)
)

df %>%
  group_by(CountryName) %>%
  mutate(Year2 = lag(Year, 1),GDP2 = lag(GDP, 1), CHANGE_PERC = ((GDP - GDP2) / GDP2 ) * 100) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric,
              round,
              digits = 0) %>%
  na.omit()
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  CountryName  Year         GDP Year2       GDP2 CHANGE_PERC
  <fct>       <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
1 Costa Rica   2010 37268635287  1960  507513830        7243
2 Guatemala    2010 41338595381  1960 1043599900        3861
3 Honduras     2010 15839344592  1960  335650000        4619
4 Panama       2010 28917200000  1960  537147100        5283
```

Comment: Thank you. Apologies for the scrambled table. I can't sort out its format.